# How to isolate the variable $v$ buried deep in a relativity formula?

Tags: general-relativity

Finding $v$ in $v = L[1-(v^2/c^2)]/t$

Closest attempt: $[1-(c^2/v^2)]v = L/t$

I've been working on this since yesterday. I think I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
v = L(1-v^2/c^2)/t \hspace{10mm}\Rightarrow \hspace{10mm} (t/L)v = 1 - (1/c^2)v^2 \hspace{10mm}\Rightarrow \hspace{10mm}  (1/c^2)v^2 + (t/L)v - 1 = 0.
\end{equation}

Now use the abc formula.

Comment: Thanks! I have one question. Is there a way that one could isolate a single v on one side of the equation? My professor used v = L/sqrt[t^2+(L^2)/c^2] but didn't explain how he derived it.

Comment: The last equation is a quadratic in $v$.  You can use the quadratic formula to get your professor's answer.

Comment: After Marc's answer and your question in the comments, the solutions of the quadratic Marc wrote  are given by $$v_{\pm}=-\frac{c^2t\pm\sqrt{c^4 t^2+4 c^2 L^2}}{2 L}$$ I suppose that we need to discard $v_{-}$. So, keep $v_+$ and multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the current numerator. Expand and simplify.

Comment: @user114027 I tried substituting your professor's value of $v$ on the right-hand side of your first equation and simplified. The result did not evaluate to the same value of $v$. There is a stray factor of $\sqrt{1 + L^2/(c^2 t^2)}$. Maybe I made a mistake, but you might want to try this yourself.